# Is this an instance of Priori Incantatem?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, wandlore, fantastic-beasts-where-to-find-them

During the climax of *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*, Tina briefly duels with Graves and their wands appear to lock with each other (see picture). I believe this also happens some other times in the later *Harry Potter* films other than Harry and Voldemort's duel in the graveyard during *Goblet of Fire*.

[image: Tina and Graves duel, showing the beams of light from their wands colliding and seeming to lock together]

We know that this is definitely a case of Priori Incantatem for the graveyard duel in *Goblet of Fire*, as the wands are locked for a sufficient amount of time for past spells to begin showing themselves (significantly, showing the people Voldemort had murdered), but is this the case for the other instances of wands locking? If so, does that mean there are a lot more wands out there with shared cores, as it was my understanding this could only happen if that criteria was satisfied?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## It’s not said to be Priori Incantatem.

In the official screenplay, when Tina duels Graves, it’s never described as causing an instance of Priori Incantatem.

> “SCENE 101
>   
> EXT. TIMES SQUARE—NIGHT
>
> *Graves is moving nearer and nearer to the Obscurus, which continues to scream and wail at his presence. He takes out his wand, poised . . .*
>
> *Tina runs into view behind Graves. She fires at him, but he turns just in time, his reactions marvelous, astounding.*
>
> *The Obscurus now vanishes. Graves, thoroughly irritated, advances on Tina, deflecting her spells with perfect ease.*
>
> GRAVES
>   
> Tina. You’re always turning up where you are least wanted.
>
> *Graves summons an abandoned car, which whooshes through the air, forcing Tina to dive out of the way, just in time.*
>
> *By the time Tina has gathered herself up from the ground, Graves has Disapparated.”* 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them (The Original Screenplay)*</sup></sub>

This likely means it’s not intended to be Priori Incantatem, since if it was, that’d likely be mentioned specifically in the official screenplay.

## It’s likely their spells colliding.

It seems the filmmakers are using that particular effect to indicate spells colliding against each other in a duel, not wands locking together.

> “More Killing Curses flew past Harry’s head from the two remaining Death Eaters’ wands; they were aiming for Hagrid. Harry responded with further Stunning Spells: red and green collided in mid-air in a shower of multi-coloured sparks and Harry thought wildly of fireworks, and the Muggles below who would have no idea what was happening –” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 4 (The Seven Potters)*</sup></sub>

A similar effect to what’s seen when Tina and Graves duel is used when Dumbledore and the Dark Lord duel, and Dumbledore has the Elder Wand, so his wand can’t possibly be the twin of the Dark Lord’s wand.

[image: GIF of Voldemort and Dumbledore dueling, showing the light from the wands colliding]

This is different than the effect used to show Priori Incantatem, which has a shimmery webbing surrounding the wizards whose wands’ twin cores are causing it to occur as well as their spells colliding, making it a distinctly different effect.

[image: GIF of Priori Incantem, showing bright webbing surrounding the participants]

It’s likely that when Tina and Graves duel, it’s just their spells colliding, not their wands connecting in Priori Incantatem.

Comment: Then why do their wands lock?

Comment: @Nemon27 My guess would be it’s just special effects for the movie.

Comment: Feel like they're playing with the rules for cinematic effect if that's the case... Maybe I need to edit my question, but I was more wondering what it means for wands to lock together and if that's always an instance of Priori Incantatem. Like I say I'm sure it happens in the *Harry Potter* series, definitely in the films (I'll try to find more pictures), although I can't remember if it ever happens in the books other than between Harry and Voldemort. Also, that excerpt from the screenplay doesn't even mention their wands locking, which they clearly do, so I'm not sure that clears it up.

Comment: @Nemon27 The filmmakers seem to be using that particular effect to show spells colliding in duels, rather than wands locking together in Priori Incantatem. The webbing surrounds Harry and the Dark Lord when they cause Priori Incantatem, but there’s no webbing around the other instances where two spells meet in the middle. Therefore it seems likely that the spells meeting in the middle is just meant to show them colliding. I’ve updated my answer with more proof.

Comment: Good stuff, clears it up mostly. Just one final thing - is this purely cinematic or have spells colliding/wands connecting in this way been known in the books? I always thought dueling was an exchange of offence spells and defence spells rather than collide spells and wait to see who's the stronger witch/wizard?

Comment: @Nemon27 Spells have been shown to collide in the books. One example: *“Harry responded with further Stunning Spells: red and green collided in mid-air in a shower of multi-coloured sparks and Harry thought wildly of fireworks, and the Muggles below who would have no idea what was happening –” - Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 4 (The Seven Potters)* Another: *“Ron and Harry shouted together; their spells collided and the monster was blown backwards, its legs jerking horribly, and vanished into the darkness.” - Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 32 (The Elder Wand)*

Comment: Cheers, that covers everything, just wish the films had more of a back and forth and clever countering of spells in their duels rather that this collision effect. An amazing display of knowledge as always, I'll accept the answer now

Comment: @Nemon27 Thanks a lot! :) The films certainly do rely more on the collision effect than the books. I’m glad you like my answer and thanks for the acceptance! :)